# Change Form Field when select option changed in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Okay, so I have a code like below

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#Topic').change(function(){
    $('[name="keycategory[]"]').prop('disabled', false);
    selection = $(this).val();    
    switch(selection)
    { 
      case 'Sport':
        $('#Sport').show();
        $('#Entertainment').hide();
        $('#Entertainment[name="keycategory[]"]').prop('disabled', true);
        break;
      case 'Entertainment':
        $('#Entertainment').show();
        $('#Sport').hide();
        $('#Sport[name="keycategory[]"]').prop('disabled', true);
        break;
      default:
        $('#Sport').hide();
        $('#Entertainment').hide();
        $('#Sport[name="keycategory[]"], #Entertainment[name="keycategory[]"]').prop('disabled', true);
        break;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="testing.php">
  <select name="Topic" id="Topic">
    <option disabled selected> -- Select Topic -- </option>
    <option value="Sport">Sport</option>
    <option value="Entertainment">Entertainment</option>
  </select>

  <!--Topic: Sport-->
  <div id="Sport" style="display:none">
    Soccer <input type="text" name="keycategory[]">
    <br>
    Basketball <input type="text" class="form-control" name="keycategory[]">
  </div>

  <!--Topic: Music-->
  <div id="Entertainment" style="display:none">
    Movie <input type="text" class="form-control" name="keycategory[]">
    <br>
    Music <input type="text" class="form-control" name="keycategory[]">
  </div>
</form>
```

With the code above, I will get the size of keycategory[] = 4. My question is, how to only send the keycategory[] with the selected topic without differing the name. This is because I got a php file which has a function that receives keycategory[] despite of the topic selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case/switch statments, modify them so they disable the hidden div inputs like

```
    case 'Sport':
        $('#Sport').show();
        $('#Entertainment').hide();
        $('#Entertainment [name="keycategory[]"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            break;
    case 'Entertainment':
        $('#Entertainment').show();
        $('#Sport').hide();
        $('#Sport [name="keycategory[]"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        break;
    default:
        $('#Sport').hide();
        $('#Entertainment').hide();
        $('#Sport [name="keycategory[]"], #Entertainment [name="keycategory[]"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        break;
```

This will prevent them from being submitted with the form.
Also, dont forget to 'reset' the fields by making them enabled before the switch statement

```
    $('[name="keycategory[]"]').prop('disabled', false);
    switch(selection)
    {
       .
       .
```

Comment: remember to enable them when showing, after they are disabled